# Completely positive trace preserving maps: Hermiticity and Kraus operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information, density-operator

A density matrix is defined in general as the operator

$$
\hat{\rho} = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle \langle\psi_i|
$$

for the most general mixture of states $\{p_i \longrightarrow |\psi_i\rangle\}_{i=1, ..., N}$.

Every density matrix has the following properties:

1. Hermiticity: $\hat{\rho}^{\dagger} = \hat{\rho}$
2. Normalisation: $\mathrm{Tr}\,(\hat{\rho}) = 1$
3. Positiveness: $\langle\phi|\hat{\rho}|\phi\rangle\geq 0 \;\;\; \forall|\phi\rangle$
4. If it describes a pure state, then it is also a projector

When describing a quantum channel, we are asking that the output of the channel is still a legitimate quantum state, therefore that is is described by a density matrix, so we ask that the map is *completely positive* (namely it must preserve positiveness, even if we only look at a sub-system of an entangled state) and *trace preserving* (CPTP).

**My questions**

1. What about Hermiticity? Is this automatically assured by the two properties (CP) and (TP)?
2. Are all these properties automatically guaranteed when implementing a quantum channel using Kraus operators?

Comment: My guess is that since your eigenvalues are real (and positive on top of that) then your matrix is hermitian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not an expert regarding quantum channels etc., but I think this is a pure math question. Let's assume that we're working on a finite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

In finite dimensions, the defining properties of a density matrix $\rho$ are positive semi-definiteness $\rho \geq 0$ and the trace-normalization $\mathrm{Tr}\,\rho=1$. Properties $1$ and $4$ are *consequences* of this definition. In particular, a positive semi-definite operator is hermitian$^\dagger$.

To answer your first question: Let $\phi$ denote a map which maps positive semi-definite operators to positive semi-definite operators. Following the considerations above, we see that if $\rho$ is positive semi-definite, then $\phi(\rho)$ is hermitian.

I don't know if I correctly understand your second question, but note that Kraus operators preserve the normalization and positive semi-definiteness. To see this, define for a density operator $\rho$ the following map: $$\varphi(\rho):= \sum\limits_k B_k \,\rho \, B_k^\dagger \quad , $$

with $\displaystyle \sum\limits_k B_k^\dagger\, B_k = \mathbb I$, where $\mathbb I$ denotes the identity operator. We find
$$ \mathrm{Tr}\,\varphi(\rho) = \mathrm{Tr}\, \sum\limits_k B_k\, \rho\,B_k^\dagger  = \mathrm{Tr}\, \sum\limits_k B_k^\dagger B_k\, \rho = \mathrm{Tr}\, \mathbb I\,\rho = \mathrm{Tr}\,\rho = 1 \quad , $$

where we've used the linearity and the cyclic property of the trace. Moreover:

$$\langle \psi|\varphi(\rho)|\psi\rangle = \sum\limits_k \langle \psi|B_k\, \rho \,B_k^\dagger|\psi\rangle = \sum\limits_k \langle \underbrace{\psi_k|\rho|\psi_k\rangle}_{\geq 0} \geq 0   \quad , $$

with $|\psi_k\rangle := B_k^\dagger|\psi\rangle$.

So $\varphi(\rho)$ is a density matrix again and therefore pure if and only if it is a projector. However, note that Kraus operators can change the purity of a density operator, cf. [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/can-kraus-operators-change-a-mixed-state-into-a-pure-state) quantum computing question.

---

$^\dagger$ This is easy to see: For a positive semi-definite $\rho$, define the following hermitian operators:
\begin{align}
\rho_1 &:= \frac{1}{2} (\rho+ \rho^\dagger) \\
\rho_2 &:=  \frac{1}{2i} (\rho -\rho^\dagger) \quad .
\end{align}
Then obviously $\rho = \rho_1 + i\,\rho_2$ and since $\langle \psi |\rho|\psi\rangle , \langle \psi |\rho_1|\psi\rangle , \langle \psi |\rho_2|\psi\rangle  \in \mathbb R$, it follows that $\langle \psi|\rho_2|\psi\rangle \overset{!}{=}0$ for all $|\psi\rangle$. Thus $\rho_2=0$ and $\rho=\rho_1$, i.e. $\rho$ is hermitian.

Comment: I agree with almost everything but I was just puzzled at the following thought: matrix $A=-\mathbb{I}$ is Hermitian but it doesn't seem positive definite as $\langle e_i|A|e_i\rangle=-1$, where is a basis element, i.e. $e_i=[0,..,1,...,0]$. Im surely making a silly mistake!

Comment: The reverse direction of the statement in the answer is incorrect, as you've noticed correctly. In other words: From positive semi-definite, hermiticity follows. The reverse is wrong (you've provided a counter example).

Comment: Of course, I see it now :). Silly of me... 

Comment: One further question that came to mind. I guess that given a $\rho$ there are many in general not positive/trace preserving maps that happen to preserve the positivity and trace of the particular given $\rho$. However, without any knowledge about $\rho$, other than it's trace and positivity, is a Krauss map the most general such map? I guess my question is a convoluted way of saying: is a Krauss map the unique general solution to a quantum map?

Comment: Dear @FriendlyLagrangian sorry, I really don't know. Perhaps it would be the best to open a separate, new question.

Comment: If $B_k$ is not unitary, which usually isn't unless there is only one Kraus operator, I don't think it makes sense to define the state $B_k |\psi\rangle$

Comment: @Suriya Sorry, I don't understand. Can you elaborate? Of course, if $B_k$ is any (linear) operator, it (linearly) maps a vector to another vector, which suffices for that argument. The point is that for any positive semi-definite (linear) operator $A$ and any (linear) operator $B$ it holds that $B^\dagger A B$ is positive semi-definite as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm giving it a second thought and I think it doesn't matter as long as it is a vector. The notation confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Phi$ be a *quantum map*, that is, a linear function between linear operators. Say $\Phi:\operatorname{Lin}(\mathcal H_A)\to\operatorname{Lin}(\mathcal H_B)$.

The first property you discuss seems to be what is generally referred to as the map being "Hermitian-preserving". In other words, the property that $\Phi(X^\dagger)=\Phi(X)^\dagger$ for all $X\in\mathrm{Lin}(\mathcal H_A)$. This amounts to $\Phi(\rho)$ being Hermitian for any Hermitian $\rho$.

Every *positive* (and thus in particular every completely positive) quantum map is Hermitian preserving, but the opposite isn't true. For example, $\Phi(\rho)\equiv \operatorname{Tr}(\rho)\sigma_x$, with $\sigma_x$ Pauli $X$ matrix, is Hermitian-preserving but not positive.

One way to characterise this is to observe that a map is Hermitian preserving *iff* its Choi opreator, $J(\Phi)\equiv\sum_{ij} \Phi(|i\rangle\!\langle j|)\otimes|i\rangle\!\langle j|$, is Hermitian. On the other hand, a map is completely positive *iff* its Choi is (Hermitian and) positive semidefinite. For completeness, let me also mention that the map is positive *iff* its Choi is (Hermitian and) positive on product states (meaning $\langle u,v|J(\Phi)|u,v\rangle\ge0$ for all vectors $u,v$).

Regarding the Kraus decompositions: a map that can be written as $\Phi(X)=\sum_a A_a X A_a^\dagger$ is automatically completely positive (and furthermore a channel if also $\sum_a A_a^\dagger A_a=I$).
If a map is just Hermitian preserving, you can still kinda write a "Kraus-like" decomposition, because any such map can be decomposed as
$$\Phi(X)=\sum_a \epsilon_a A_aX A_a^\dagger, \,\,\epsilon_a\in\{-1,1\}.$$
This again follows from the tight relation between eigendecompositions of the Choi operator (or more generally its decompositions in terms of unit-rank positive operators), and Kraus decompositions of the corresponding channel. See also [this answer on qc.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21168/55) about it, and links therein.

You'll find a lot more info aobut these topics *e.g.* in chapter 2 of [Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/TQI).